# Swift - custom default component with delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uikit

I want to write a custom text view by inheriting default UITextView. My implementation uses some of the methods from the delegate of the original component:

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {
    fileprivate func applyStyles() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.borderColor = .black
        self.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        applyStyles()
        delegate = self
    }    
}

extension CustomTextView: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("aaaa")
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("bbbb")
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this text view everywhere instead of the standard one, but in the current implementation, I lose the ability to set another delegate to the component without losing the delegate functions of my own.
I mean if I will create a component in other class like this:

```
let customView = CustomTextView()
customView.delegate = self
```

textViewDidBeginEditing and textViewDidEndEditing functions in CustomTextView will not be called. How can I get around this limitation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to override the `delegate` property, so that you can capture any value that is assigned and then call that delegate after your code is done.  For this to work, your subclass will need to implement *all* of the `UITextViewDelegate` functions in order to pass the invocation on to the "real" delegate:

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    private weak var externalDelegate: UITextViewDelegate?

    override var delegate: UITextViewDelegate? {
        set {
            self.externalDelegate = newValue
        }

        get {
            return self.externalDelegate
        }
    }

    fileprivate func applyStyles() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        super.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        super.delegate = self
    }
}

extension CustomTextView: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("aaaa")
        self.externalDelegate?.textViewDidBeginEditing?(textView)
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("bbbb")
        self.externalDelegate?.textViewDidEndEditing?(textView)
    }

    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        return self.externalDelegate?.textViewShouldEndEditing?(textView) ?? true
    }

    func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        return self.externalDelegate?.textViewShouldEndEditing?(textView) ?? true
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        return (self.externalDelegate?.textView?(textView, shouldChangeTextIn: range, replacementText: text)) ?? true
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        self.externalDelegate?.textViewDidChange?(textView)
    }

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.externalDelegate?.textViewDidChangeSelection?(textView)
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        return self.externalDelegate?.textView?(textView, shouldInteractWith: URL, in: characterRange, interaction: interaction) ?? true
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        return self.externalDelegate?.textView?(textView, shouldInteractWith: textAttachment, in: characterRange, interaction: interaction) ?? true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the reason may be unclear behind the fact that you want the callback to be triggered both inside the custom textview class and the parentVc , but you can do

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView , UITextViewDelegate {
   weak var parentVC:VCName?

 func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    print("aaaa")
    parentVC?.textViewDidBeginEditing(self)
 }
```

---

```
let customView = CustomTextView()
customView.parentVC = self
```

or do the reverse which is to make the parentVc as the delegate and call the methods of textView subclass from it

Comment: The reverse is working as expected, but I just want to write a drop-in replacement to UITextView. With the approach you described, I will always need to override methods textViewDidBeginEditing/textViewDidEndEditing even if they are not used in a new delegate.